Spring Gateway with Spring Auth + Resource server - getting CORS error
gateway-url=http://127.0.0.1:9090
authorization-url=http://127.0.0.1:6060
resource-url=http://127.0.0.1:8080
public-spa-url=http://localhost:4200

I have an Angular UI that access a resource server through a Spring Gateway.
The problem I have is that when the authorization server authorizes, it redirects to the following URL:
Note: here I followed this old guide: - where credentials are sent via an Angular form!
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js#_the_resource_server_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_iii
To summarise: Angular sends credentials via a form, that puts these in a Basic HTTP Auth header, and then tries to access an end point in the resource server. The gateway intercepts the request (right now does nothing with Angular Auth header), and sends its own client credentials on to the Auth Server, which then creates this URL
http://127.0.0.1:6060/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=api_gateway_client&scope=openid&state=oKol3_tz9yD1-iSQC8p7EUSAIkPaQNKAqx8lYFvxKxk%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/in-house-auth-server&nonce=zh7y02wAKSahkN1AQ0ve5vrQI-QViyelMWqsbbiagRc

So, I think, it asks the browser to go back to authorization server, with the above link, but now, since the auth object is in the security context, it doesn't redirect to the auth server's login page, but detects the previously authorized user, and uses the request cache kept in a short lived http session, to eventually redirect the user to the gateway (the embedded redirect_url starting with 127..9090), which should pick up the nonce token, and re-direct the user, via the gateway to the resource server (with the access token).... OR, I think the gateway just sends its client credentials again, with the above link in order to get the access token (since I'm using auth code grant with pkce - so it's slightly different to the client credentials authorization grant method)
But either way, that doesn't happen. The browser complains at this point:

Access to script at 'http://127.0.0.1:6060/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=api_gateway_client&scope=openid&state=Pz6Rq1XIcIFT94h7xYoc5hVSfglyTAdQrngnfvLoY6E%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/in-house-auth-server&nonce=biFP__E5abph275Kf7kM5q9HKE6YJg7yErrhcAzosvM' (redirected from 'http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js') from origin 'http://localhost:9090' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The browser response headers on that call look like this:
GET /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=api_gateway_client&scope=openid&state=S_xrtLz45aFQazwTUz22OYmyeq-gwWmTCZNdxof6qLQ%3D&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/in-house-auth-server&nonce=izAjxewKfaMdPx3jWafGnVzp-YO18iJUwv6fMXBG2VQ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:6060
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"

I have CORS configured in the gateway as follows:
 // configure cors
    .cors { cors ->
        cors.configurationSource {
            CorsConfiguration().apply {
                // ensure this matches the Angular app URL
                allowedOrigins = listOf("http://localhost:4200")
                allowedMethods = listOf("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                allowedHeaders = listOf("Content-Type", "Authorization", "X-XSRF-TOKEN")
                exposedHeaders = listOf("Content-Type", "Authorization", "X-XSRF-TOKEN")
                // required if credentials (cookies, authorization headers) are involved
                allowCredentials = true
            }
        }
    }

I even tried to route the UI via the gateway, by doing this (and changing the CORS allowed origin to 9090, if it helped at all):
 @Bean
    fun routeLocator(builder: RouteLocatorBuilder): RouteLocator {
        return builder.routes()
            // routing for Resource Server
            .route("resource-server") { r ->
                r.path("/resource/**")
                    .filters { f ->
                        f.prefixPath("/api")
                            .filter { exchange, chain ->
                                // Add your custom filter logic here if needed
                                chain.filter(exchange)
                            }
                            .tokenRelay()
//                            .saveSession()
                    }
                    .uri(resourceUrl)
            }
            // routing for User Interface
            .route("public-spa") { r ->
                r.path("/ui/**")
                    .uri(publicSpaUrl)
            }
            .build()
    }

But I kept getting the same error.
Lastly the api gateway is a registered client in the auth server, where I use the auth code, grant type
// api-gateway client (gateway client!)
        val apiGatewayClient = RegisteredClient
            .withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId(apiGatewayClientId)
            .clientSecret(apiGatewayClientSecret)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
            .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/in-house-auth-server")
            .tokenSettings(
                TokenSettings.builder()
                    .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.SELF_CONTAINED)
                    .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                    .refreshTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
                    .authorizationCodeTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                    .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                    .build())
            .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID) // requests an ID token, which is necessary for any OpenID Connect request.
            .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE) // requests access to the user's profile information (e.g., name, date of birth)
            .clientSettings(ClientSettings
                .builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true)
                .build())
            .build()

Lastly, how would I authenticate the login credentials sent by Angular in the Request Auth Header, all the way to the Auth server - as right now Authorization happens by the Gateway sending its client credentials to the auth server.
Where am I going wrong?
UPDATE
Ok. as suggested below, I'm scrapped following the old guide, and tried to followg the full BFF pattern, as suggested by ch4mpy
I'm stuck here though, with a casting error on the bff server:
Angular Error

Auth Server - Looks ok

BFF - Error

full Github code below in the comments


If the resource server endpoint is protected then it will redirect to the authorization server

That's wrong. To get tokens, OAuth2 flows are used by OAuth2 clients (all of it, including the authorization-code). OAuth2 resource servers only care if tokens are valid (issued by a trusted authorization server, not expired, right audience, etc.), not about how these tokens are issued (which flow to use or even if user login is involved).

Angular sends credentials via a form

That's wrong too. This is not how the authorization-code flow works. Your Angular app should not have access to user credentials. Actually, it should not even be an OAuth2 client. If you browse down to the Final Recommendation of this post from Spring Security team, you'll read that their current recommendation is using an OAuth2 BFF.
I wrote an article on Baeldung detailing the configuration of SPAs (Angular, React, and Vue), Spring Cloud Gateway as OAuth2 BFF (with oauth2Login and the TokenRelay filter), and stateless resource server(s) (Spring REST APIs with oauth2ResourceServer).

Access to script at 'http://127.0.0.1:6060/oauth2/authorize [...]  from origin 'http://localhost:9090' has been blocked by CORS policy

What you need is to redirect the user to the authorization server (temporarily exit the SPA & change the origin), not to send a cross-origin from the SPA to the authorization server.
For that, instead of letting the browser follow the 302, I set the window.location.href with the value of the Location header. But, for the SPA code to be able to handle the redirection to the authorization endpoint by setting the window location, I change the status of the BFF response from 302 to something in the 2xx range.

Here is the code so far: https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/tree/master/Spring%20BFF  - my auth server (servlet) is slightly stateful, as I need to hold onto the original request url, so need a session to store that, and then re-direct to that original url on authenication. I set the session duration to 5 seconds, but I'm not sure if that is best practice or if I'm doing it the right way...but it sort of works. my resource server (webflux) is stateless. My gateway (webflux) is stateful. I currently send my login request via an Auth Header, from Angular, which holds onto cookies.

The CORS error you report isn't on the redirection back from the authorization server to the client (as your first comment suggests). See my updated answer (and read the article).

Ok, I’m going to have another go and read the article. Separately, do you do short term 1-2 day consultancy work? Eg if I paid you, would you be willing to help for a day, or so? I’ve been trying to configure Spring Security for 6 weeks, with a simple login and Google SSO from Angular. I’ve also read the 2nd edition book. I can send further details with an offer by email. I could really benefit from an expert like you

Honestly, if you follow the article (and use "my" starter) you should get things working by yourself for free in less than 4 hours.

Ok, I'm halfway though! (75+ config files, but there you go). https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/tree/master/Spring%20BFF - I've gotten a little more than halfway through the article. A bit I don't get: when I call the resource server via the reverse proxy >> bff >> resource server, it just calls the end point, even though i have a token relay in the bff (it doesn't redirect to the auth server to ask for login credentials? how is it meant to do that via the reverse proxy?) Then is the auth server also meant to store auth object state? hope to understand the Angular part tomorrow.

Both authorization servers and clients with oauth2Login are stateful. And each maintains a session of its own. Only resource servers can, and should, be stateless. So in a horizontally scaling environment, you'll need something like Spring Session or a smart proxy (routing requests from a given device to the same instance) for the authorization server and BFF. Yes, auth server keeps a state for the user (this is how things like SSO, tokens refreshing, introspection, and logout work). In the tutorial, the decision to redirect to the auth server for login is taken by the SPA, not the BFF.

You might initiate this redirection by intercepting the 401 returned by the resource server(s) (and bubbling up through the BFF and reverse proxy). Another option is to use route guards. The tutorial is designed to display links to routes requiring authorization only when the user is logged in (and has the required role if this is relevant). In this configuration, no need for guards or interceptors.

I've referenced the Spring Security Guide I followed, where credentials are sent via an Angular form (what I originally wrote in my post). But I've followed your suggested BFF pattern, but am hitting a casting error issue on the Bff server. I've raised it with the Spring Security team, as I couldn't work out how to debug it.

I don't know how old this article is, but as it uses WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, it can be considered as completely outdated. I've read in a comment you deleted that you don't want want to use spring-addons because you don't know what it does. Well, that's just a regular Spring Boot starter. So it applies the configuration listed in resources (mind the many conditions on configuration files and beans).

Sorry if it looks condescending, but considering your knowledge of OAuth2, Spring Security, and Spring Boot, I doubt that you achieve anything working & safe without following the article and using "my" starter.

Thanks ch4mp. I’m back to using the spring Addons package. I read your separate GitHub read me on that. Yes you’re right, my knowledge of Spring is limited. Hence the offer for help through consultancy work in my very first comment if you’re still open to it. It certainly is taking me more than the 4 hours. I have indeed read your article, three times, with a fine tooth comb. The code examples are helpful as they show the reverse proxy too (at the very end of your article). I’m  stuck on a different error now, which I’ve raised with the spring security team. Hopefully I can progress
